# Is there a way to extend makeStyle classes in Material UI?

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I want to be able to achieve something like this:

```
const useStyles = makeStyles((theme) => ({
  button: {
    backgroundColor: 'red',
    border: 'black solid 5px',
  },
  selectedButton: {
    extend: 'button',
    backgroundColor: 'yellow'
  }
}))
```

So class 'selectedButton' would still have a black border but the background color will change.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using `makeStyles`

```js
const button = {
  backgroundColor: "red",
  border: "black solid 5px",
};

const useStyles = makeStyles({
  button,
  selectedButton: {
    ...button,
    backgroundColor: "yellow"
  }
});
```

[image: Edit zen-platform-gylg4]

Using `withStyles`

```js
const StyledButton = withStyles({
  root: {
    backgroundColor: "red",
    border: "black solid 5px"
  }
})(Button);

const SelectedButton = withStyles({
  root: {
    backgroundColor: "yellow"
  }
})(StyledButton);
```

[image: Edit hardcore-lumiere-26zpr]

Comment: Thanks. I didn't include in my original question, but to access the theme prop of makeStyles within my button base class, I declared 'const button' within the makeStyles return function instead of above it and it works fine.